# Swift: applicationDidBecomeActive in UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in iOS Programming. I want to ask is there any method that equivalent with `applicationdidbecomeactive` for **UIViewController** in **UIView**? I need to update my view everytime it's become active after running in the background. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NotificationCenter` here.

You can register an observer in view in which you want the notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appIsActivited), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
```

When app becomes active then a notification is fired and `appIsActivited` method will be called.

```
 @objc func appIsActivited() {
    //do something
}
```

**Note: Don't forgot to remove observer from view once it is no more needed to releases view's occupied memory.**

Comment: Note in Swift 4.2: NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appIsActivited), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

Comment: don't forget to remove the obesrver when `deinit` is called

Comment: You don't need to remove observers since iOS9+. Looks like it uses weak links so memory will be correctly deallocated.